# mySQL query to filter a field is not like given pattern

Tags: mysql

I have an mySQL query to select all fields from the table where the username in the table doesn't start with "Abc\". I tried to create the query but it is not working.

```
Select * from User where username NOT LIKE 'Abc\%'
```

But is not working. I am new to queries and can manage to write simple queries but this one I am not sure if I am following the correct way.

Comment: Try escaping \ to \\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape slash (\). In mysql slash (\) is used to escape characters in a like query.

```
Select * from User where username NOT LIKE 'Abc\\\\%'
```

Comment: Why do we need 4 slashes(\) , does one slash is not enough to escape the slash in (Abc\). I am little confused.

Comment: You can get the explanation here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html


To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Comment: But if I use like Select * from User where username NOT LIKE 'Abc\\\\%' it is pulling all the records from the User, but I need the records only if the username that doesnot starts "Abc\"